# How to troubleshoot Windows 7 hibernate problems?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I have regular sporadic problems bringing my Windows 7 64-bit notebook (running in a domain) to hibernate state.

About 50% of the time it goes to hibernate within 2 minutes and resumes properly. In other cases it takes more than 5 minutes and I observed cases, when it finally shut-ed down, but at restart told me, that it was not shut-down correctly.

I found this promising link  > http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_sleep_problem.htm.

But in my event-log I found no entries about problems to enter sleep-mode or hibernate.

I find only a lot of  [Event ID 41](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504) entries, but none of the events mentioned by Guy.